# Calling JS function from C# Page load

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, webforms

I am trying to call js function from code behind using C#, but it is not working. Below is my code

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "Sys.Application.add_load( function(){ setText(" TExt ")});", true);
```

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page,this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "Sys.Application.add_load( function(){ Mret.FormInputControl._setText(" + string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "'{0}','{1}'", this.ID, TextHeader) + ")});", true);
```

Following are different way to call javascript function from code behind

Solution 1:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Hello');", true);
```

Solution 2:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page,this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Hello');", true);
```

Solution 3:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page,this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Hello');", true);
```

Comment: You can try this because it work for update panel or without update panel

Comment: I have tried it. Wanted to know if my script is right inside Scriptmanager

Comment: Can you try if this work ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page,this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert(123);", true);

Comment: I have tried all at my side. All are working. Have you tried with alert?

Comment: Or can you check browser developer console if any error?